# Tensorboard import error in keras.callbacks

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, importerror, tensorboard

I'm following sentdex's video on Neural Networks with Keras.

My tensorflow version is 2.0.0.

I'm on Windows 10 and running this code in an Anaconda Jupyter environment.

I have tried searching up or this error but I have got no results.

**Code**:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Tensorboard

import pickle
import numpy as np
import os
import time

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

NAME = "CATS-VS-DOGS-CNN-{}".format(int(time.time()))

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))

pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("y.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=8, epochs=10, validation_split=0.3, callbacks = [tensorboard])
```

**Error**:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a32bf5fe83d7> in <module>
      5 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
      6 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
----> 7 from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Tensorboard
      8 
      9 import pickle

ImportError: cannot import name 'Tensorboard' from 'tensorflow.keras.callbacks' (C:\Users\anves\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\api\_v2\keras\callbacks\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you notice, you're importing `Tensorboard` (with a small 'b'):

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Tensorboard
```

but when you're creating the callback, you're using `TensorBoard` (with a capital 'B'):

```
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))
```

So, you need to import `TensorBoard` (with a capital 'B') as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
```

Below's a screenshot that shows the same correction:

[image]

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard.
Hope this will surely work.

Screenshot of my notebook:
[Notebook for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia8Bm.png)

Comment: its been over 2 years since ive asked this question, but thanks regardless lmao